# How can I get test case name and use it as file name NLog

Tags: c#, file, nunit, nlog

I have the following question. I want to create new **.txt** file for every test case run with the test case name or test case id (it doesn't matter)as **file name** but I don't know how to get the current test case name in the **NLog.Config** file.

```
<target name="logfile"
            xsi:type="File" 
            layout="${longdate}|${message}" 
            fileName="${basedir}\ATF\web\utils\reports\${shortdate}\${callsite}.txt"  />
```

I am using **${callsite}**, but I have logger in several classes and it creates files with the names of theses classes.

```
        private static readonly Logger Logger = GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

**E.g.** I have one class logging that some Selenium action is completed, another class logging the driver is opened successfully. In the test I am using both classes and I don't want to create file for every class I use, but only one file with the test name.

P.S The logger itself is working properly. 
 I am using **NUnit** for the tests.

So if anyone knows how because I couldn't find what I want, I will be very thankful.

Have a nice day!

Comment: How do you run your testcase? Which test framework is used?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't metion. I am using Nunit and Nunit Test Adapter

Comment: Can you share the code of classes an tests? _I have logger in several classes and it doesn't work as I want to_ what is not working here? Please, provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using NUnit TextContext inside a custom NLog LayoutRenderer:

```
[LayoutRenderer("nunit-testname")]
public class NUnitTestNameLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        builder.Append(NUnit.Framework.CurrentContext?.Test?.Name);
    }
}
```

Compile the above code into an assembly called "Custom.NLog.NUnit", and then you can load it like this:

```
   <extensions>
      <add assembly="Custom.NLog.NUnit" />
   </extensions>
   <targets>
      <target name="logfile"
              xsi:type="File" 
              layout="${longdate}|${message}" 
              fileName="${basedir}\ATF\web\utils\reports\${shortdate}\${nunit-testname:whenEmpty=UnknownTest}.txt"  />
   </target>
```

See also: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestContext

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer

Comment: Hello @Rolf Kristensen and thank you very much for the response. If you only can tell me what is the best way to compile into an assembly as I am new to C# . Anyways, one more time I appreciate the help. :)

Comment: @npazderov You just place the source-code in a C#-project in your solution, and the C#-project will compile into an assembly. Maybe a good idea to find some books about designing/building solutions in C#.

Comment: Happy new year. I've just used wrong assembly name, I've changed it and everything is perfect and I think this is the better approach to reach the goal. Thank you one more time @Rolf Kristensen

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution using NLog NDLC:

```
    [Test]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        using (NLog.NestedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Push(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString()))
        {
             // Testing within "${ndlc}"
        }
    }
```

Then you can do this in your NLog-Layout:

```
target name="logfile"
            xsi:type="File" 
            layout="${longdate}|${message}" 
            fileName="${basedir}\ATF\web\utils\reports\${shortdate}\${ndlc:topFrames=1:whenEmpty=UnknownTest}.txt"  />
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Ndlc-Layout-Renderer